# INVALID_SESSION_ID While Switching Users

Tags: salesforce-sdk-android

I am using SalesforceSDK for Android in one of my apps. The issue I am facing is, I am not able to re-login as a different user after logging out. 
The code I am using for logout the current user is

```
SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().logout(this);
```

After that the login screen comes. But while I try to login as a different user, it throws the below error and goes back to login screen again.

```
{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}
```

If I re-login as same user, I am not getting this error. 
To successfully re-login as a new user, I have to kill the app from background and then relaunch it.

Kindly help me on this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a single instance of the `SalesforceSDKManager`? Can you create a new one after performing the logout?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thank you for the response, Daniel. But I didn't see an option to create a separate instance of SDKManager. If you have done this earlier, could you please add some code snippet which I can use?

Comment: I'd suggest raising it as an issue in Github - [SalesforceMobileSDK-Android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues)

Comment: Okay. I saw an updated library of SalesforceSDK in GitHub. In the sample app in that repo, the logout functionality is working fine. I am now trying to integrate it.